# How to see expert only in own city in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

My project have two role

- admin
- expert

[image: Database]

admin must see all data of all city.
expert must see all data of own city after registered.

```
public function index()
{
    $schools = SchoolsList::latest()->paginate(25);
    $city_id = SchoolsList::where('city_id')->first();
    $expert = Role::where('id', '=', 2);
    if ($expert){
        return view('Admin.inspection-failed.all', compact('schools')->where(($city_id)));
    }
    else{
        return view('Admin.inspection-failed.all', compact('schools'));
    }
}
```

Table of school

```
Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
    $table->string('school_name');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('gender');
    $table->string('notes');
    $table->string('member_name');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->string('file_number');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('address');
});
```

I want to when a expert login. Expert display data only own expert city.

I get this error.

> Call to a member function where() on array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error becomes  in this code`compact('schools')->where(($city_id))`; because `compact('schools')` it is equivalent `['schools' => $schools]`. 
See documentation  http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php.
 And in your case  your code is equivalent `['schools' => $schools]->where(($city_id))`. 
For fix it you must be use 

Short Answer

```
$schools = $schools->where('city_id' => $city_id->id);
return view('Admin.inspection-failed.all', compact('schools'));
```

Long Answer

```
$city = City::first(); // you must be fix it yourself
$expert = Role::where('id', '=', 2); // you must be change it

if ($expert) {
    $schools = SchoolsList::latest()->paginate(25);
} else {
    $schools = SchoolsList::where('city_id', $city->id)->latest()->paginate(25);
}

return view('Admin.inspection-failed.all', compact('schools'));
```

Comment: I dont understand. What you mean??

Comment: Role expert display own cities after expert login.

Comment: Your error come in this code `compact('schools')->where(($city_id))` which i detailed explained. Other past of you code also is wrong designed.